# Why is my React Dates component not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, react-dates

Can't seem to work out how to fix React Dates without breaking something different each time

I have this:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment().subtract(2, 'year'))
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null)
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState('startDate')



const onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    setStartDate(startDate)
    setEndDate(endDate)
}


<DateRangePicker
    endDate={endDate}
    endDateId="endDate"
    focusedInput={focusedInput.focusedInput}
    isOutsideRange={() => null}
    onDatesChange={onDatesChange}
    onFocusChange={(focusedInput) => setFocusedInput({ focusedInput })}
    startDate={startDate}
    startDateId="startDate"
/>
```

so first error I get is this: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_isAMomentObject, _isUTC, _pf, _locale, _d, _isValid})`

so then I've tried various things like this:

```
const onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    setStartDate(moment(startDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    setEndDate(moment(endDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY)
}
```

and setting the initial state to null. but then that gave me an `invalid date` error

All I want to do is set 2 different dates in a range and it seems incredibly complicated

Comment: Can you create a snippet for this using the library used for DateRangePicker. The issue is related to moment function returning object. Change this line to const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment().subtract(2, 'year').format('DD-MM-YYYY'))

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha tried that and still not working

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 I'm using React-Dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the comment on the github page here [github](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/issues/1726#issuecomment-510662884)
You have to import react-dates/initialize

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-dates/initialize";
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-dates";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment().subtract(2, "year"));
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState("startDate");

  const onDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    setStartDate(startDate);
    setEndDate(endDate);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <DateRangePicker
        endDate={endDate}
        endDateId="endDate"
        focusedInput={focusedInput.focusedInput}
        isOutsideRange={() => null}
        onDatesChange={onDatesChange}
        onFocusChange={focusedInput => setFocusedInput({ focusedInput })}
        startDate={startDate}
        startDateId="startDate"
      />
      ;
    </div>
  );
}
```

Refer this sandbox link also. https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-currying-9jydi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey I think my problem is in the function `onDatesChange`, when I select an `endDate` it's blowing up because startDate is coming back as Invalid Date?

Comment: Great you figured it out.

Comment: Did you check the sandbox link. I don't see any issue there though.

Comment: I don't understand how yours works. mine breaks straight away when I put `const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment().subtract(2, 'year'))`